# Manipulating expression ParametricPlot

Tags: manipulate, parametric-functions, ellipse

How can I make Mathematica plot the curve being traced by the focii of the ellipse?
I know the traced curve would be drawn in an instant, when I switch the variable from u to t, but I want the curve to be plotted when varying the u-value during manipulate.

Code:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{
  {4 Cos[u] Cos[t] - 2 Sin[u] Sin[t] + 
     2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], 
    2 Cos[u] Sin[t] + 4 Sin[u] Cos[t] + 
     2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}, 
  {2 (Sqrt[3] Cos[u] + Sqrt[
       4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2]), 
    2 (Sqrt[3] Sin[u] + Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2])}
  }, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> 
   {Line[{{4 Cos[u] + 2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], 
       4 Sin[u] + 2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}, {-4 Cos[u] + 
        2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], -4 Sin[u] + 
        2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}}], 
    Line[{{-2 Sin[u] + 2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], 
       2 Cos[u] + 2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}, {2 Sin[u] + 
        2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], -2 Cos[u] + 
        2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}}]
   }
  ], {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- We can plot the trace of the focii as below.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  Block[{u = v}, {2 (Sqrt[3] Cos[u] + Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2]), 
    2 (Sqrt[3] Sin[u] + 
       Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2])}], {v, $MachineEpsilon, u}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}], {u, 0, 2 π}]
```

- And using `Show` to combine the two plots.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[{{4 Cos[u] Cos[t] - 2 Sin[u] Sin[t] + 
      2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], 
     2 Cos[u] Sin[t] + 4 Sin[u] Cos[t] + 
      2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
   Epilog -> {Line[{{4 Cos[u] + 2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], 
        4 Sin[u] + 2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}, {-4 Cos[u] + 
         2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], -4 Sin[u] + 
         2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}}], 
     Line[{{-2 Sin[u] + 2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], 
        2 Cos[u] + 2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}, {2 Sin[u] + 
         2 Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2], -2 Cos[u] + 
         2 Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2]}}]}], 
  ParametricPlot[
   Block[{u = v}, {2 (Sqrt[3] Cos[u] + Sqrt[4 Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2]), 
     2 (Sqrt[3] Sin[u] + 
        Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 Sin[u]^2])}], {v, $MachineEpsilon, u}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]], {u, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]